# Bluemix MQ light Queue Depth checking programmatically

Tags: queue, ibm-cloud, mq

What is the suggested mechanism for finding the Bluemix MQ light Service queue depth. We have millions of messages which needs to be pushed into queues, since queue depth is limited to 10000 in MQ light, we might run in a situation, where queue depth gets breached out.  Since with MQ we use Queue Manager to Query the current depth of the Queue and control the push rate. What is the suggested way to control this in Bluemix, without breaking the application.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that there is not a way to query the depth of an MQ Light for Bluemix queue.

I'm assuming you are using the JMS API as you are using queuing, and JMS does not provide an API for administrative functions, such as querying queue depth.

Even using the JMS QueueBrowser interface to count the messages on the queue could be a bad idea - apart from needing to read every message on the queue, which will be slow, it will cost - as each browsed message will count towards the cost of the service.

Comment: What is the suggested way out in such a scenario, were we are trying to control the push rate at which messages are pushed at ?